# Manipulate scientific format without the "e"

Tags: text-processing, awk

I am trying to manipulate a file which contains numbers in scientific notation, but without the `e` symbol, i.e. `1.2e+3` is written as `1.2+3`.

The easiest thing I thought of doing with `awk` was to replace `+` with `e+`, using the `gsub` function and do my calculation in the new file. The same goes for the minus case. So a simple fix could be done using the following command

```
awk '{gsub("+", "e+", $1); print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5}' file_in
```

and do the same in all the columns.

However the file contains also negative numbers which makes things a bit more complicated. A sample file can be seen bellow

```
 1.056000+0 5.000000-1 2.454400-3 2.914800-2 8.141500-6
 2.043430+1 5.000000-1 2.750500-3 2.698100-2-2.034300-4
 3.829842+1 5.000000-1 1.969923-2 2.211364-2 9.499900-6
 4.168521+1 5.000000-1 1.601262-2 3.030919-2-3.372000-6
 6.661784+1 5.000000-1 5.250575-2 3.443669-2 2.585500-5
 7.278104+1 5.000000-1 2.137055-2 2.601701-2 8.999800-5
 9.077287+1 5.000000-1 1.320498-2 2.961020-2-1.011600-5
 9.248130+1 5.000000-1 3.069610-3 2.786329-2-6.317000-5
 1.049935+2 5.000000-1 4.218794-2 3.321955-2-5.097000-6
 1.216283+2 5.000000-1 1.432105-2 3.077165-2 4.300300-5
```

Any idea on how to manipulate and calculations with such a file?

Comment: How do you want to make calculations with a format like that 2.698100e-2-2.034300e-4 ?

Comment: This looks like it's probably meant to be parsed as [fixed-width column data](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Fixed-width-data.html). The apparent whitespace between columns is just an artifact of the number format displaying positive values with a leading space instead of a plus sign.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Is this output correct?

```
 1.056000e+0 5.000000e-1 2.454400e-3 2.914800e-2 8.141500e-6
 2.043430e+1 5.000000e-1 2.750500e-3 2.698100e-2-2.034300e-4
 3.829842e+1 5.000000e-1 1.969923e-2 2.211364e-2 9.499900e-6
 4.168521e+1 5.000000e-1 1.601262e-2 3.030919e-2-3.372000e-6
 6.661784e+1 5.000000e-1 5.250575e-2 3.443669e-2 2.585500e-5
 7.278104e+1 5.000000e-1 2.137055e-2 2.601701e-2 8.999800e-5
 9.077287e+1 5.000000e-1 1.320498e-2 2.961020e-2-1.011600e-5
 9.248130e+1 5.000000e-1 3.069610e-3 2.786329e-2-6.317000e-5
 1.049935e+2 5.000000e-1 4.218794e-2 3.321955e-2-5.097000e-6
 1.216283e+2 5.000000e-1 1.432105e-2 3.077165e-2 4.300300e-5
```

Code:

```
perl -lne 's/(\.\d+)(\+|\-)/\1e\2/g; print' sample
```

Explanation:

- `-lne` take care of line endings, process each input line, execute the code that follows
- `s/(\.\d+)(\+|\-)/\1e\2/g`:

  - substitute (`s`)
  - `(.\d+)(\+|\-)` find two groups of (a dot and numbers) and (a plus or minus)
  - `\1e\2` substitute them with the first group then `e` then the second group
  - `g` globally - don't stop at the first substitution in each line, but process all possible hits
- `print` print the line
- `sample` input file

This one adds space if it's missing. In fact it puts space between the numbers regardless. Ie. if there were two spaces in some case, there would be only one in the output.

```
perl -lne 's/(\.\d+)(\+|\-)(\d+)(\s*)/\1e\2\3 /g; print' sample
```

Most of it is similar to the previous one. The new thing is the `(\d+)` group nr 3 and the `(\s*)` group nr 4. `*` here means optional. In the substitution no `\4` is used. There's a space instead.

The output is this:

```
 1.056000e+0 5.000000e-1 2.454400e-3 2.914800e-2 8.141500e-6 
 2.043430e+1 5.000000e-1 2.750500e-3 2.698100e-2 -2.034300e-4 
 3.829842e+1 5.000000e-1 1.969923e-2 2.211364e-2 9.499900e-6 
 4.168521e+1 5.000000e-1 1.601262e-2 3.030919e-2 -3.372000e-6 
 6.661784e+1 5.000000e-1 5.250575e-2 3.443669e-2 2.585500e-5 
 7.278104e+1 5.000000e-1 2.137055e-2 2.601701e-2 8.999800e-5 
 9.077287e+1 5.000000e-1 1.320498e-2 2.961020e-2 -1.011600e-5 
 9.248130e+1 5.000000e-1 3.069610e-3 2.786329e-2 -6.317000e-5 
 1.049935e+2 5.000000e-1 4.218794e-2 3.321955e-2 -5.097000e-6 
 1.216283e+2 5.000000e-1 1.432105e-2 3.077165e-2 4.300300e-5
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!
Yes it seems correct!! Can you explain what you did, for future reference?

Comment: Is it also possible to separate the last column ($5$) from the previous one with a space?

Comment: You are perfect! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Thanos See the update. And notice I added a backslash before `.` in the first group. This is correct. Without this backslash the dot would not mean a literal dot.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `sed`, e.g.:

```
<infile sed -E 's/([0-9])([+-])([0-9])/\1e\2\3/g' | awk '{ print $1 + 0 }'
```

However, this does not take into account that the columns in OP's listing are sometimes not separated. Here is a workaround with appropriate precision:

```
<infile sed -E 's/.{11}/& /g'       |
sed -E 's/([0-9])([+-])/\1e\2/g'    |
gawk '{ print $1 + 0 }' OFMT='%.7g'
```

Output:

```
1.056
20.4343
38.29842
41.68521
66.61784
72.78104
90.77287
92.4813
104.9935
121.6283
```

Comment: This removes resolution from the numbers, and I'm not sure it will work when a negative value is next to another like the example in the question `2.698100-2-2.034300-4`

Comment: @pipe: You are right, I missed that detail.  I have added a workaround by adding space. Wrt. precision, I used the `OFMT` variable to set awk's precision to the same as the input's